# É possível criar um streaming de um para varios com webRTC?

Tags: javascript, streaming, webrtc

Preciso desenvolver uma ferramenta que permita fazer uma live de um único pc para vários outros em uma sala virtual.
Para isso escoli usar o webRTC https://webrtc.org/start/ 
De forma simples já consigo fazer o pc pegar o video e o áudio. porém não consigo transmitir os mesmos.
Alguém poderia me dar um norte?

Comment: Sim é possível!
Confere esse link: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/multiple/